# Next 90 day review date (Teradata)

Tags: datetime, date, sequence, teradata

Teradata Related question… I have a table containing new starters along with a start date, every 90 days from the start date I need to conduct a review with the starter

How do I identify the next 90 day review date for the new starter?

For example, If the start date was back in 2017, I would want it to show the next 90 day review date as at today (so given we’re in 2022, when is their next review date?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: The information (table) about the reviews already created by the starter must exist. And this information must be taken into account.

Comment: Sample data and expected results (as text) are essential. Please also tag your DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Follows example with table creation, insertion of data and applying rule (rule described below) for every row.

```
CREATE TABLE #starter (starterdate datetime);
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO #starter (starterdate) VALUES 
('2017-05-23'),('2017-09-23'),('2019-10-12'),('2022-10-17');
COMMIT;


SELECT DATEADD(DAY, IIF(DATEDIFF(DAY,starterdate,GETDATE())>90, DATEDIFF(DAY,starterdate,GETDATE()) ,90),  starterdate) FROM #starter

DROP TABLE #starter;
```

What this script does, is following:

- creates temporary tables
- inserts 4 records with various dates in the past
- selects all rows

**Then on every row:**

1. checks what is the difference between the value in table and TODAY
2. if the difference is > 90 days, it returns todays date
3. if the difference is < 90 days, it returns the date in the table + 90 days

Lastly, the temporary table is dropped.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL syntax:

```sql
SELECT starter_name
FROM starters_table
WHERE NOT (DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, starter_date) MOD 90)
```

The query selects the starters whose "next review" date is today.

```sql
SELECT starter_name,
       starter_date + INTERVAL 90 * CEILING(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, starter_date) / 90) DAY next_review_date
FROM starters_table
ORDER BY next_review_date ASC;
```

The query shows "next review" dates for all starters.

Both queries assumes that the datatype for `starter_date` column is DATE.

Comment: That’s great, however I’m getting an syntax error saying “expected something like a string or a Unicode character literal between the ‘INTERVAL’ keyword and the integer 90? Should of mentioned that I’m running in Teredata

Comment: @Spindo82 *I’m running in Teredata* This is critical info. Tag your question accordingly. *I’m getting an syntax error saying* Wrap the expression between the keywords INTERVAL and DAY with CAST(.. AS CHAR) or VARCHAR.

Comment: Hi Akin, I’m not sure what you mean sorry, can you display the code you mean, apologies if this is an inconvenience

Comment: @Spindo82 `.. starter_date + INTERVAL CAST(90 * CEILING(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, starter_date) / 90) AS CHAR) DAY ..`

Comment: Teradata is using Standard SQL syntax for intervals,  would be `INTERVAL '90' DAY * ...`, but this is shorter `starter_date + ceiling((current_date - starter_date)/90) * 90`

Comment: @dnoeth The problem was in the fact that Teradata which performs implicit casts in many cases does not perform it in this particular case .. by some unknown reason.

Comment: The "newer" data types like TIME/TIMESTAMP/INTERVAL need explicit typecasts (to be compliant with Standard SQL)